# QGIS WMS/WMTS layers only renders as "Singleband color data"

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, symbology, wmts

I'm trying to visualize some height rasters on QGIS 3.18 (Windows and Mac). The problem is that only the "Singleband color data" band rendering mode is available in the layer's properties/ symbology. I'm missing the modes normally available with raster data (Multiband color, Paletted/Unique values, Singleband gray, Singleband pseudocolor, Hillshade, Contours). I've tried several different WMS/WMTS sources and updated versions of QGIS 3.18, now on 3.18.2. Should all the modes be possible also with WMS/WMTS sources?

Comment: WMS returns a picture of the data not the actual data so there is no way to style it in the client.

Comment: I don't understand why symbology like "Singleband Pseudocolor" is disabled for WMS. WMS are not always derived from vectors and some WMS providers provide singleband images. It would be useful to manipulate the color space within QGIS.